# android TabLayout set icon from server

Tags: android

can i set icon from server on `TabLayout` using `Picasso` library

```
private string path = "192.168.0.102/project/a.png";

TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.aaa));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.bbbb));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ccc));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.eee));
```

but i don't want icon from resId i want to set icon from my server
     `tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(path ));`

or must i use another class for this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a tab item with a custom view. Look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#setCustomView(android.view.View)).

See the following example:

```java
private View createTabItemView(String imgUri) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    TabLayout.LayoutParams params = new TabLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    Picasso.get.load(imgUri).into(imageView);
    return imageView;
}
```

Now, you can add tab items with a custom view.

```java
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(createTabItemView("image URL")));
```

Answer (score 0):

A newer approach :

```
        for(int i = 0; i<tabs.size(); i++){
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        int finalI = i;

        Picasso.get().load(tabs.get(i).getIcon()).into(iv, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                tab_layout.getTabAt(finalI).setIcon(iv.getDrawable());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {

            }
        });
    }
```